# NodeJS Seqeulize One-to-One Relationship not real in Database Level?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am learning NodeJS and I came across with a situation which confused me a little bit. I could not find an answer to it in internet so decided to ask here. Sorry beforehand for any mistake.

So I am using Sequelize as ORM for MySQL. I created 1:1 relationship between User and Cart model as below

```
const User = sequelize.define("User", {
  _id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
  autoIncrement: true,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.STRING,
});

const Cart = sequelize.define("Cart", {
  _id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
  autoIncrement: true,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  },
});

User.hasOne(Cart);
Cart.belongsTo(User);
```

This creates relationship and I can use methods which is result of this relationship but the problem is in Database I can create limitless Cart instances with all having same user as reference. How can this be? After searching all day I think I got some little ideas but not complete answer.
As I understood there is no 1:1 association in SQL level but it is in ORM level actually.
Is this right? If no, What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!